# Generate OAuth2 token for Google Apps Directory Sync without a GUI

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-apps

The instructions for setting up Google Apps Directory Sync (GADS) says to use the *config-manager* to get the OAuth2 token. The config-manager uses a GUI. I am trying to set-up GADS on a Linux server without a desktop.

Is there any way to accomplish this task from the command-line without a full visual user interface?

Answer (score 1):

The step-by-step process is as follows:

1. Setup GADS on a graphical desktop (Windows/Mac/Linux), choose the
   various options as required and save the config file (the xml file).
2. Install GADS at your non-GUI machine (e.g. Linux server).
3. Copy the xml config file created in step 1, to this non-GUI setup and then run the commands listed at [this Google's product support page](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6165113#nogui) to re-set the passwords and authentication tokens such as the Oauth2 token.

I'm listing the commands for completeness sake (assuming you're running from the installation directory e.g. `/usr/local/GoogleAppsDirSync` under Linux):

- To reset your LDAP credentials, enter:

  `./upgrade-config -ldapuser LDAP_username -ldappassword LDAP_password -c config_file_name`
- To authorize your Google Apps domain via OAuth, enter:

  `./upgrade-config -Oauth Google_Apps_domain_name -c config_file_name`

You would be prompted to copy-paste a long URL into a graphical browser to obtain the Oauth token, which needs to be copied back into the command line prompt to set the token.

- Test the LDAP connection, by entering:

  `./upgrade-config -testldap -c config_file_name`
- Test the Google Apps connection, by entering:

  `./upgrade-config -testgoogleapps -c config_file_name`